# Difference between rows in KDB/Q

Tags: kdb

I'm new to KDB/Q and have a question around getting the difference between two (not necessarily adjacent) rows.

I have only one table, which looks like the below:

```
q)tickers:`ibm`bac`dis`gs`ibm`gs`dis`bac
q)pxs:100 50 30 250 110 240 45 48
q)dates:2013.05.01 2013.01.05 2013.02.03 2013.02.11 2013.06.17 2013.06.21 2013.04.24 2013.01.06

q)trades:([tickers;dates];pxs)
q)trades
tickers dates     | pxs
------------------| ---
ibm     2013.05.01| 100
bac     2013.01.05| 50
dis     2013.02.03| 30
gs      2013.02.11| 250
ibm     2013.06.17| 110
gs      2013.06.21| 240
dis     2013.04.24| 45
bac     2013.01.06| 48
```

I would like to be able to have a either another column in the table that stores the difference between the current and the previous price, or another structure similar in structure. The key question that the resulting needs to answer is "by how much did the stock change compared to the previous time a price was recorded?"

So far I've tried something along the lines of:

```
select tickers, dates, pxs - pxs(dates bin (exec dates from trades where tickers = trades.tickers)) from trades
```

which doesn't really work (at all). Definitely due to trying to do SQL-like queries and having a row-oriented mindset.

Please find below an exemple of the sought after answer:

```
q)trades: do magic with trades
q)trades
tickers dates     | pxs | delta
------------------| --- | -----
ibm     2013.05.01| 100 | 0
bac     2013.01.05| 50  | 0
dis     2013.02.03| 30  | 0
gs      2013.02.11| 250 | 0
ibm     2013.06.17| 110 | 10
gs      2013.06.21| 240 | -10
dis     2013.04.24| 45  | 15
bac     2013.01.06| 48  | -2
```

Thanks for your help,
Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
q)update delta:{0,1_deltas x}pxs by tickers from trades
   tickers dates     | pxs delta
   ------------------| ---------
   ibm     2013.05.01| 100 0
   bac     2013.01.05| 50  0
   dis     2013.02.03| 30  0
   gs      2013.02.11| 250 0
   ibm     2013.06.17| 110 10
   gs      2013.06.21| 240 -10
   dis     2013.04.24| 45  15
   bac     2013.01.06| 48  -2
```

Comment: To clarify the inline, anonymous function `{0,1_deltas x}`: Comma is the list join operator, and `1_` means drop first entry from deltas result.  Since the function is called without `'` or `each`, the function is called only once with the full column of data.  If `0,1_` is removed, the first delta will be `100`, which is normally undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

if you do:

```
select pxs by dates,tickers from table
```

you will have a complex column (pxs) which is a list of prices for the particular date and ticker. You can then apply deltas:

```
select deltas pxs by dates,tickers from table
```

Which will give you the running difference. The first value is the original pxs though so you'll need to update the first one to 0.

EDIT

Just re-read and having looked at your result, you'll need to join back to your original trade table

Answer (score 1):

update dates, pxs, delta:(0N,(-1_ pxs) - 1_ pxs) by tickers from trades

Please find how it works:
select pxs by tickets from trades
creates table which rows contains: ticket and list pxs.
So in every row we have a list:

```
tickers| pxs
-------| -------
bac    | 50  48
dis    | 30  45
gs     | 250 240
ibm    | 100 110
```

now we have to apply function which will calculate delta. Best function mentioned above: deltas, but my version is about the same.

if we select - then we will have table with tickers|list of pxs|list of deltas, but is we use update .. by, then it ungroup groupped values.

Comment: Some verbiage explaining your answer would make this a useful answer; simply typing in code is not really the point, as it doesn't teach effectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same results using the `prev` function. One thing worth highlighting that `prev` automatically adds the null (`0N`) as the first element. This is important as we don't have the previous information available, however, adding a `0` as the first element suggests that there has not been any change; though it depends on how you want to handle the first record.

```
q)update delta:pxs-prev[pxs] by tickers from trades
tickers dates     | pxs delta
------------------| ---------
ibm     2013.05.01| 100
bac     2013.01.05| 50
dis     2013.02.03| 30
gs      2013.02.11| 250
ibm     2013.06.17| 110 10
gs      2013.06.21| 240 -10
dis     2013.04.24| 45  15
bac     2013.01.06| 48  -2
```

using `deltas` to get the same results (`0N` instead of `0`)

```
q)update delta:{0N,1_deltas x}pxs by tickers from trades
```